# How to get the column name in sql-server for which the insert fails due to coulmn size issue

Tags: sql-server

While trying to insert below record into my users table,`sql-server` is showing me `String or binary data would be truncated` error message.

How can I get the exact column name for which the insert operation is failing.

```
insert Users(name,age) values ('DummyUser',20);

TABLE [dbo].[Users](
[name] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
[age] [int] NULL
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforunately there is no way to know which column is the culprit. You will need to go through the annoying elimination process.

There is a long-standing open request to improve on the error message here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Maximum Columns Limit

Bytes per short string column 8,000

Bytes per GROUP BY, ORDER BY 8,060

Bytes per row 8,060

Columns per index key 16

Columns per foreign key 16

Columns per primary key 16

Columns per nonwide table 1,024

Columns per wide table 30,000

Columns per SELECT statement 4,096

Columns per INSERT statement 4096

Columns per UPDATE statement (Wide Tables) 4096

When you combine varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, or CLR user-defined type columns that exceed 8,060 bytes per row

**Creating table with n number of columns and datatype Nvarchar**

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[CreateMaxColTable_Nvarchar500]
(@TableName nvarchar(100),@NumofCols int)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @j VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @len int
SELECT @i=1
SELECT @MAX=@NumofCols
SET @SQL='CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '('

WHILE @i<=@MAX

BEGIN
select @j= cast(@i as varchar)
SELECT @SQL= @SQL+'X'+@j  +' NVARCHAR(500) , '
SET @i = @i + 1
END
select @len=len(@SQL)

select  @SQL = substring(@SQL,0,@len-1)


SELECT @SQL= @SQL+ ' )'

exec (@SQL)

END
```